# Getting started with OSX kernel programming

Tags: macos, kernel

For someone familiar with Linux kernel programming, what are some resources for getting started with OSX kernel programming? I've read some of the Apple Developer resources, but they seem fairly generic (e.g. basic concurrency control primitives). Specifically I am interested in file system development.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Amit Singh's book "Mac OS X Internals" contains a chapter describing the Implementation of HFS+, which might be helpful. If you find resources describing BSD's VFS layer, that might help too, as that's where OS X's VFS layer originates (though with its own page cache, called the Unified Buffer Cache or UBC). Moreover, you could try poking around in the source code of MacFuse and its descendants. Looking at the source of some of the simpler file systems (HFS+ is a bit big for this) will probably also help.

Comment: Ahh, I forgot that MacFuse was open. Good suggestion, thanks. Do you know of any resources for setting up a development environment? I'd prefer to stay away from XCode, but would also like to know if that is simply the best option.

Comment: @NoahWatkins I've always used XCode, at least for building. It comes with a CLI utility called `xcodebuild` which lets you build projects without opening XCode itself - then you only need to open XCode for adding source files to the project. There's of course nothing stopping you from building with whatever build system you like: XCode gives you a detailed build log, so you just need to replicate those commands in your build system of choice. The critical flag for the compiler is `-mkernel`.

Comment: @NoahWatkins for practicalities such as memory management, synchronisation, setup and debugging, you might also want to look at Ole Halvorsen's OSX Kernel book, even though it doesn't cover the VFS. (disclosure: I was a tech reviewer for that book; I receive no incentives for recommending it however)